# How to RUN LARAVEL after closing all connections

Tags: laravel, xampp

I have shut down my laptop and now how to continue on same project which I had proceeding at beginning,
I started XAMPP but still URL shows NOT FOUND for my directory .

i run it using :**php artisan serve**
Then URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000
it shows not found page

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve` in terminal to start your project?

Comment: Start run `php artisan serve` and check `localhost:8000` in your browser.

Comment: Show your route(web.php) and HomeController.php code

Comment: thanks bro it workes now i hade problem inside route

Answer (score 0):

As laravel and php development environments, I highly recommend these to you.

Windows : https://laragon.org/
Mac OS :https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet

Answer (score 0):

1. At first, open your cmd
2. Now get into the folder where you started your laravel project
3. Once you are in the laravel project through CMD run the command "php artisan serve"
4. Now you may check the URL once again.
   I also faced the same issue hence tried to answer.
   Thank you.